With or without the definite article in: the/Internet and the/television are a popular media
Should I add "the" or "a" in (in modern life) or there is no need to add any article?
Or should I say "both internet and television are a popular media" Or "both the internet and the television are a popular media"?

Have you tried looking in a dictionary? (Also I don't think the internet is normally called a medium/type of media - streaming TV and online newspapers would be media, but you could consult Wikipedia.)

We speak of the Internet because there is only one, but television (without any article) because it is a method of broadcasting, not a single system.
However, it's incorrect to say a media. It's actually the Latin plural of medium (of communication). In modern life we talk about 'the media', meaning all the different methods of mass communication (TV, radio, books and newspapers, and so on). So you should say

Both the Internet and TV are popular media.


"We speak of 'the Internet' because there is only one, but 'television' (without any article) because it is a method of broadcasting, not a single system." This needs justification (I doubt it's possible), as 'We heard it on the radio' is/was standard.

Also good: "Both the Internet and TV are popular communication mediums."

@user8356 - Not according to this

That website's advice refers to two of the same type of media outlets as not deserving of the plural "mediums." I don't consider the Internet and TV as part of "the media". I consider them separate mediums.

@user8356 - Actually, it says Generally, if the topic is communication or the arts, we use "media."
